# Complexity - which is the best and worst case in this algorithm in C?

Tags: data-structures

In this algorithm, N tends to infinity (asymptotic analysis). In which situations that lead to the best and worst case?

```
int i=1;
while(i < N)
  i = i + 3;
if(B[6] < 100)
  for(int j=1; j<N/2; j++){
    int k=j+1;
    while((k<N) && (k > j)){
      printf("%d", B[k]);
      k++
    }
  }
```

What i found:
best case O(N)
worst case: O(N^2)
Is correct? why?

This is a data structure question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: no... I found the answer I put to the question, but I'm not sure, I have difficulties with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I misread the initial question and have edited my answer

First I'd try to simplify the code a little.

We know that in the expression `(k < N) && (k > j)`, `k` is always greater than `j` since it is initialized to `j+1` and we ignore overflow.

That gives us:

```
int i = 1;
while(i < N) // O(N)
  i = i + 3; // O(1)

if(B[6] < 300) // Only consider what's inside in the worst case
  for(int j = 1; j < N / 2; j++) // O(N)
    int k = j + 1;               // O(1)
    while(k < N)                 // O(N)
      printf("%d", B[k]);        // O(1)
      k++;                       // O(1)
```

We perform O(N) work inside the `while(i < N)` loop and perform constant time work (`O(1)`) inside it if we do not go into the if statement. We then multiply `N * 1` to still get `O(N)`

This gives us the best case runtime of O(N).

Now for the worst case assume we also go inside the if statement. This means we execute the for loop which does `O(N/2)` work which is still `O(N)`. Inside the for loop is another while loop that performs `O(N)` work as well.

We then multiply `O(N)` from `for(int j = 1; j < N / 2; j++)` and `O(N)` from `while(k < N)` since they're nested and get `O(N^2)`.

We then add the initial `O(N)` and the `O(N^2)` to get `O(N^2 + N)` which is really just `O(N^2)` since we only care about the highest scaling term. This makes `O(N^2)` the worst case runtime.

Comment: This is not correct. The first while loop is independent of the for loop. Note the lack of braces after the while statement.